# Is a private individual shopping for personal goods from companies "non-commercial"?

Tags: copyright, united-kingdom, fair-use, commerce

Suppose Alice is interested in buying something for her personal use, completely unrelated to her work or making money.  She investigates the products produced by Bob Inc. and Charlie Corp., both for-profit companies producing these products in the course of their business.

Is what Alice is doing commercial or non-commercial?  For example would any research she engages in be covered by the [text and data mining for non-commercial research](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/exceptions-to-copyright#text-and-data-mining-for-non-commercial-research) exception to [Copyright Law](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/60180c2b8fa8f53fc62c5897/Copyright-designs-and-patents-act-1988.pdf)?

Comment: What work is Alice copying while investigating the products produced by Bob Inc. and Charlie Corp?

Comment: @Lag A web site scrape was what I was thinking about.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes and no

Yes, it is a non-commercial activity for Alice.

No, it is a commercial activity for Bob Inc. and Charlie Corp.